# After redirecting to canonical domain and HTTPS, Google Search Console reports most of my pages are now excluded

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, https, search-engine-indexing

In Google Search Console - Coverage for one of my sites it says :

```
Error 0
Valid with warnings 22
Valid 10
Excluded 11.1k
```

Expanding Excluded, it's 6,000 for pages with redirect and 3,400 with a soft 404

Examples in the redirect are HTTP URLs which have been re-directed to HTTPS with a 301, this was done 9 months ago. The XML sitemap was updated too.

While moving to SSL I also made one of 2 domains canonical, see previous post:

[Move to SSL and have 2 x domains, make one canonical or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111067/move-to-ssl-and-have-2-x-domains-make-one-canonical-or-not)

Why am I seeing so few valid pages, and why has Google still got HTTP URLs after so long?

Edit: SITE: results

```
site:dog-toys.ie About 1,720 results
site:dog-toys.ie About 6,050 results
site:www.dog-toys.ie About 1,540 results
site:www.dogtoys.ie About 5,710 results
```

This it the .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.dogtoys.ie%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dogtoys.ie [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.dogtoys.ie%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did you create a new property for your HTTPS website in Search Console or are you still using the one for http?

Comment: Now that you say it, no! I guess I need to?

Comment: I just see there is a new option, to add a domain: "All URLs across all subdomains (m., www. ...)
All URLs across https or http
Requires DNS verification" - would this be better than adding https: / / www.dogtoys.ie?

Comment: I don't know about this new option but yes you should definitely tell the search console you are now working on the https version.

Comment: I'm not sure why Google takes so long to move all the pages of a site from HTTP to HTTPS, but that is my experience too.  See [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110084/14543) for details about my site which took more than 9 months to get indexed on HTTPS.

Comment: The new "domain property" option in Google Search Console will give you a more complete picture of your site.  However, you can't connect it to Google Analytics yet.  [Google Search Console domain property not in the list of properties I can add to Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122242/google-search-console-domain-property-not-in-the-list-of-properties-i-can-add-to)

Comment: Stephen- If I use the new domain option, will GA still work with normal JavaScript tags?